# Folding union-types into Either/Coproducts

Tags: scala, scala.js

Given a [pseudo-union type in Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.10/#scala.scalajs.js.$bar), how would I fold it into an `Either[A, B]` (or a coproduct)?

Comment: Fold in what sense?  Can you give more details about what you're tying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a function `toEither[A, B](union: A | B): Either[A, B]` you're out of luck. The easiest way to see this is to note that it must work for any choices of `A` and `B`, so if I specialize them both to `Unit`

```
toEither[A, B](union: A    | B   ): Either[A, B]
toEither      (union: Unit | Unit): Either[Unit, Unit]
toEither      (union: Unit       ): Either[Unit, Unit]
```

it becomes clear that any such function would need to make an arbitrary choice and thus no such function would really exist. Try this exercise with other types `C` and `A = B = C`.

Generally, unions types are convenient when you recognize that some Javascript function takes several different types of values and distinguishes them at runtime, but they're also less useful than `Either` is.

Generally, a function `toUnion[A, B](eit: Either[A, B]): A | B` is doing one thing: "forgetting" whether a value is "Left" or "Right" into the undifferentiated union. With this information destroyed you have fewer options to move forward.